# TypeORM query returns an empty array

Tags: javascript, typescript, react-native, typeorm, react-native-sqlite-storage

I'm trying to retrieve data from an existing database. I recently switched to bare workflow from Expo managed, trying to test react-native-sqlite-storage with TypeORM. However, TypeORM raw query keeps returning an empty array and I have no idea why.

Here's my code and it is based on this example https://dev.to/jgabriel1/expo-sqlite-typeorm-4mn8

**DictionaryScreen.js**

```
function DictionaryScreen(props) {
    const { ejRepository } = useDatabaseConnection();

    const handleinputWord = async () => {
        console.log(props.inputWord);  //=>this console.logs the text from the input below 
        try {
            const results = await ejRepository.getWordandMean(props.inputWord);
            
            console.log(results); //=> Here I expect an array of the query result but it only returns []

        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error)
        }
    }

    return(
                <View style={styles.searchContainer}>
                    <MaterialCommunityIcons name="text-search" color="white" size={30}/>
                    <TextInput
                        style={styles.input}
                        onChangeText={props.updateTextInput}
                        onSubmitEditing={handleinputWord}
                        value={props.inputWord}
                        placeholder='Look up the word (Type exactly)'
                        keyboardType="default"
                    /> 
                <StatusBar style='light' />
                </View>
           )
}

const mapStateToProps = state => {
    return { 
        inputWord: state.inputWord
    }
};
    
const mapDispatchToProps = {updateTextInput};
    
    
export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps) (DictionaryScreen);
```

**repository.ts**

```
export class EJRepository {
    private ormRepository: Repository<EJModel>;

    constructor(connection: Connection) {
      this.ormRepository = connection.getRepository(EJModel);
    }

    public async getWordandMean(props: any): Promise<EJModel> {
      console.log(props);  //=> this returns the same text from DictionaryScreen

      const results = await this.ormRepository.query(
        `SELECT * FROM ejmodel WHERE word LIKE '%${props}%';`, [props]);
 
      return results;
    }
}
```

**connection.tsx**

```
interface DatabaseConnectionContextData {
    ejRepository: EJRepository;
}
  
const DatabaseConnectionContext = createContext<DatabaseConnectionContextData>(
    {} as DatabaseConnectionContextData,
  );
  
export const DatabaseConnectionProvider: React.FC = ({ children }) => {
　　　const [connection, setConnection] = useState<Connection | null>(null);
  
　　　const connect = useCallback(async () => {
      　const createdConnection = await createConnection({
        　　type: 'react-native',
        　　name: "ejdict.v1.0",
        　　database: '***.db',
        　　entities: [EJModel],
           location: 'default',
       　　 migrations: [ejdict1621603544180],
        　　migrationsRun: true,
        　　synchronize: false,
           logging: true,
        　　extra: {createFromLocation: '/Users/***/***/ios/***/www/***.db' }
      　});
  
      　setConnection(createdConnection);
    　}, []);
  
    useEffect(() => {
      if (!connection) {
        connect();
      }
    }, [connect, connection]);
  
    if (!connection) {
      return <ActivityIndicator />;
    }
  
return (
  　<DatabaseConnectionContext.Provider
      value={{
        ejRepository: new EJRepository(connection),
      }}
    >
      {children}
    </DatabaseConnectionContext.Provider>
  );
};

export function useDatabaseConnection() {
  const context = useContext(DatabaseConnectionContext);

  return context;
}
```

**EJModel.ts**

```
import {Entity, PrimaryColumn, Column} from "typeorm";

@Entity({name: "ejmodel"})
export class EJModel {

    @PrimaryColumn({type: 'integer'})
    item_id: number;

    @Column({type: 'text'})
    word: string;

    @Column({type: 'text'})
    mean: string;

    @Column({type: 'integer'})
    level: number;
}
```

PS: Is it an unusual attempt to load an existing database on a React Native project? Working examples are almost no existent. I once made it work on Expo, but I realised I needed migration functionality and tried to do the same thing with TypeORM wasting lots of time...

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution for this problem by following step

1. adjust the entity of the table to

   `@Entity({
   name: YOUR_TABLE_NAME,
   synchronize: false,
   })`
2. Put the existed database into dir

   `android/app/src/main/assets or android/app/src/main/assets/www`
3. Typeorm declare

   `export const AppDataSource = new DataSource({
   type: "react-native",
   database: database.db,
   location: "default",
   synchronize: true,
   entities: [YOUR_ENTITY],
   logging: ["error", "query", "schema"],
   });`

//note that can set to false if you want all tables to not synchronize or can set individually in each Entity like step 1. 
4) In your index.android.js or App.js file, openDatabase to get connect to the database.

```js
SQLite.openDatabase(
  {
    name: "database.db",
    createFromLocation: "~database23_02_17.db",
    location: "default",
  },
  () => {
    console.log("db connection success");
  },
  () => {
    console.log("db connection error");
  }
);
```

5. Uninstall the app if you've already installed in your physical device (because the app will not update the database file) and then run build again

   `cd android &&./gradlew clean
   cd .. && react-native run-android`